# How to encrypt data going from the client to the database with SSL?

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

How to encrypt data going from the client to the database with SSL? This question has been asked in several places, and the one thing they all have in common: **USE SSL**. By the way, my goal is to update the remote database via the client. The dilemma, is that whenever I put `?useSSL=false` in my code, it works just fine. However, when I leave it out I get;

> WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended.

So I looked that up and they said:

> Your connection URL should look like the below,
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Peoples?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
> ```
>
> This will disable SSL and also suppress the SSL errors.

Well what good is that if you're trying to use SSL? How do I encrypt my data with SSL going from the client to the database?

After thoroughly reading the error that I received, I am now thinking that it is only giving me that error because I'm going to `localhost`. Is this correct? Will putting in the IP of the remote server allow me to securely transfer data via SSL?

Comment: You need to install a valid certificate on the server.

Comment: A warning is not an error. Also, who is this "they" that said you should disable usesssl? You may want to check your assumptions and check the MySQL Connector/J documentation first.